# Is there a way to prevent user from easily closing app that starts AlarmManager?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm

I am working on app to track device's position and compare it to set values. For example: parent wants to be sure that on Monday, between 8am and 3pm his kid is in the school. The app should stay on kid's phone, check its position every now and then and then compare it with school's coords within certain radius. If kid's phone happened to be out of bounds, phone would send simple notification to the parent via email, sms or whatever (haven't programmed that part yet).

My problem is that app does its job only when the it's open. And that's pretty obvious and understandable but I'd like it to work more like an alarm clock. Alarm clocks are not present in 'Recent apps' menu, so you can't easily kill it but still it goes off on time and works as desired. Also I don't have to reopen my alarm clock after restarting the phone, which as a feature could be also a great addition to my app.

I don't want it to be completely UNclosable. Just a little bit harder, so little kids or old people with memory problems could use it without closing accidentally.

Here's my code I've done so far:

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();

    //HERE WAS MY LOCATIONMANAGER MAGIC

    wl.release();
}

public void setAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 20, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute


}

public void cancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
}
```

Comment: "My problem is that app does its job only when the it's open" -- alarms are removed when the user "force stops" the app or reboots the device. Otherwise, alarms are left alone. What is your evidence that "app does its job only when the it's open"? Did you use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to see when the alarm is scheduled? Note that alarms do not fire every 20 seconds on Android 5.1+ (one-minute minimum), that `setRepeating()` is inexact as of Android 4.4, and that you cannot really do "LOCATIONMANAGER MAGIC" in `onReceive()`.

Comment: Moreover, your use case seems to be a great fit for geofences from the Play Services SDK.

Comment: @CommonsWare I know and didn't mean force stopping. I was talking about 'Recent Apps' menu in which alarm clocks usually don't appear. My app does appear there and closing it there stops scheduling next alarms. As for time, I didn't plan to check for location every that often. Every 5 minutes should be fine, I suppose. Why wouldn't I call my locationManager's functions from within onReceive() though? It seemed to work so far - sort of D:

I just started looking into geofences and it really seems like a good idea. It still leaves me with problem -- to be continued

Comment: problem of rescheduling these geofences checks whenever app is gone from 'recent apps' or after rebooting. Ideally I would like to set checks for entire week (like Monday 8am - 4pm at School, Tuesday 6pm-8pm at friend's house, etc.) and then "let it be". I'd like it to work even after recharging battery from fully-dead-state, after rebooting, after clearing recent apps and so on. I assume that users of devices with these apps will NOT know how to force stop apps.

Comment: "My app does appear there and closing it there stops scheduling next alarms" -- either you are misinterpreting the symptoms, or there is something afoot with your test environment. "Why wouldn't I call my locationManager's functions from within onReceive() though?" -- you cannot reliably perform asynchronous work in `onReceive()`, as the process may terminate before your work completes. Have your receiver start a `Service`, which does the location work and calls `stopSelf()` when it is done.